# Construct an open covering of R (with the standard metric/topology) which does not have a Lebesgue number

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble finding an open cover as described above. This question has been asked before here: [find a open cover for R that has no lebesgue number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422780/find-a-open-cover-for-r-that-has-no-lebesgue-number/2034452#2034452)

However, I believe the only answer presented is wrong as the open cover suggested does not contain 0. If I'm mistaken, please let me know and I will use their answer. Otherwise, this question deserves to be revisited.

Comment: It's a careless error.  Just define
$$
B_n := (n-\frac 1{|n|+1}, n+\frac1{|n|+1})
$$
instead so that we can include a $B_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in the other thread can be salvaged. The problem is that $B_0$ is ill-defined, since it includes a division by zero (also, there is a problem with negative $n$). Changing the definition to

$$B_n = \left(n - \frac{1}{|n| + 1}, n + \frac{1}{|n| + 1}\right)$$
yields an example by the same argumentation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I had given up on salvaging that $B_n$