# Equicontinuous on a compact set implies uniform equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, equicontinuity

*Theorem*

$(M,d), (N,\rho)$ metric spaces, $K \subset M$ compact. If $\mathcal{F} \subset F(M,N)$, where $F(M,N) = \{ f \mid f:M \rightarrow N\}$, is equicontinuous on $K$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $K$.

*Proof from class*

Suppose not. Then $\exists \; \epsilon_0>0 $ s.t. $\forall \; \delta >0 , \exists \;x' \in K, y' \in M$ s.t. $d(x',y') < \delta$ but $\rho(f(x'),f(y') ) \geq \epsilon_0$ for some $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

1)

Let $\delta = 1/n$, then $x_n \in K, y_n \in M$ s.t. $d(x_n,y_n) < 1/n$ but $\rho(f(x_n),f(y_n) ) \geq \epsilon_0$ for some $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

$\{x_N\} _{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ had a convergent subsequence  ($K$ compact.) i.e., $\exists x_{n_k} \rightarrow l \in K$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Using a $3$ epsilon argument, there is a sequence $y_{n_k}$ that converges to $l$ as well.

2)

since $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous at $l$, this implies for every $\epsilon>0$, (in particular, for $\epsilon_0$ that was fixed above) if $d(x,l) < \delta$ and $d(y<l) < \delta$, then $\rho(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon \; \forall \; f \in \mathcal{F}.$

Then, for $k$ greater than some integer $N$, $d(x_{n_k},l) < \delta$ and $d(y_{n_k},l) < \delta$, then $\rho(f(x_{n_k}),f(y_{n_k})) < \epsilon \; \forall \; f \in \mathcal{F}.$

This is a contradiction.

> I am confused about why this proof works. We proved that for the points $x,y$ that were in the particular sequence converging to $l$, $\mathcal{F}$ is unifomrly continuous. But suppose there are $x',y' \in K$ s.t. $d(x',y')< \delta$ but $d(x',l) \not < \delta$ or $d(l,y') \not< \delta$ (i.e., they are $\delta$-close but not in the sequence converging to $l$). Then we don't know if  $\rho(f(x'),f(y')) < \epsilon$, do we?

Answer (score 2):

You found a sequence $(x_n)$ that is $\delta$ close such  that $(f(x_n)$) is $\epsilon$ close for all $f\in \mathcal F$, for large enough $n$. This is a contradiction of the original hypothesis.

There is an easier,  direct proof that uses  the [Lebesgue number lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/explanations-of-lebesgue-number-lemma), the proof of the existence of which is not hard and can be found in most topology texts.

By equicontinuity for each $x$ there is $\delta_x>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon/2$ for all $f\in \mathcal F$. The balls $\{B(x,\delta_x)\}_{x\in M}$ cover $M$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue number for the cover. Then, if $d(x,y)<\lambda,$ there is a ball $B(z,\delta_z)$ such that $x,y\in B(z,\delta_z).$ It follows now from the triangle inequality that $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ for all $f\in \mathcal F$.

Comment: I am confused. Would the contradiction be "$\forall \;x' \in K, y' \in M$ s.t. $d(x',y') < \delta$ but $\rho(f(x'),f(y') ) \geq \epsilon_0$ for  all $f \in \mathcal{F}$? we didn't prove for all $ x' \in K, y' \in M$, we proved for a sequence ?