# Is this proof that arguing equicontinuousness in a compact set is uniformly continuous valid?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

This is a theorem that was discussed in class but I came up with another proof.

The theorem is: Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. If $X$ is compact, and $h$ is a set of mappings from $X$ to $Y$ and is equicontinuous everywhere in $X$, then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.\forall f\in h,x,x'\in X(d(x,x')<\delta\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(x')<\epsilon)$.

My proof is as the following:

Fix $\epsilon$.

Let $\phi(x_0):=\max{\lbrace \delta>0|\forall f\in h,x\in X(d(x_0,x)<\delta\Rightarrow d(f(x_0),f(x)<\epsilon)\rbrace}$, then since $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\phi(x)=\phi(x_0)$, we know that $\phi$ is a continuous mapping.

Since compact sets in metric space are closed sets, $X$ is a closed set, which means $\phi(X)$ is a closed set on $\mathbb{R}$, so $\min \phi(X)$ exists, and any $\delta$ satisfies $\delta < \min \phi(X)$ is the $\delta$ we find.

Is this correct?

Comment: Where does $x_0$ appear in the RHS of your definition of $\phi(x_0)$?

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: What's your proof that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \phi(x) = \phi(x_0)$?

Comment: Oops... Seems like I simply assumed this proposition without any proof and I find that I don't know how to proof it. Can you proof whether this is correct or not? Thank you!

Comment: Your proposed proof reminds me of this proof of the Lebesgue number lemma: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105346/405572. Indeed, a common proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523409/equicontinuous-on-a-compact-set-implies-uniform-equicontinuous) of your desired proposition is proven using the Lebesgue number lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed proof reminds me of [this proof of the Lebesgue number lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105346/405572) (in fact, a common proof of your desired proposition is proven using the Lebesgue number lemma -- see [Equicontinuous on a compact set implies uniform equicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523409/equicontinuous-on-a-compact-set-implies-uniform-equicontinuous)).

I think that essentially the same technique used to prove $r(x)$ is continuous in the [first answer I linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105346/405572), can show that your $\phi(x)$ is continuous. Indeed, fixing $\epsilon>0$, we can define
$$U := \bigcup_{x_0 \in X} \{x \in X: d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon, \; \forall f\in \cal F\}$$
which is an open set because it is the union of open sets (the sets on the RHS are open I think by equicontinuity?), and your $\phi(x_0)$ is exactly $r(x_0,U):= \sup\{\delta>0: B(x_0,\delta) \subseteq U\}$.

For a brief proof sketch that $r$ is continuous, Ctrl-F "Lebesgue number lemma" [in this pdf](http://danielrui.com/papers/manifoldsIntro.pdf), and read the paragraph preceding the light-blue lemma box.

Comment: It's very useful! Thank you!

Comment: @LythrumSawyeraa since you are a new user, I should tell you that you can upvote answers you find useful, accept answers you think answer your question. Of course you can always ask further questions in the comments, if you are not happy with current answers.