# Path lifting lemma - proof clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, compactness, fundamental-groups

So i was studying the proof of the 'path lifting lemma' on my book and I got stuck.
Here $ S^1 $ is identified with complex numbers of norm 1 and $ E: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1 $ is defined by $ E(x)= e^{2\pi ix}, x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Lemma**: If $ \alpha $ is a path in $ S^1 $ with starting point  1, there exist a unique path $\alpha '$ in $ \mathbb{R} $ with starting point $0$ such that $ E \alpha ' = \alpha $.

**Proof**: Because **I** is compact and $ \alpha $ is continuous, we can choose subintervals of  **I**, $ [t_0,t_1],...[t_{n-1},t_n],\  0=t_0 < t_1$ $ <...< t_n=1$ such that $$|\alpha (t) - \alpha (t')| < 1 \; \forall t,t' \in [t_{i-1},t_i] \;\; \forall i=1...n
\; \; \; \; \; \; \;\; \; \; \; \; \; \;\; \; \; \; \; \; \;
\textbf{(1)} $$
and so such that $$ \alpha ([t_{i-1},t_i])\mbox{ is contained in } S^1 \backslash \{ - \alpha (t_{i-1}) \} \;\; \forall i=1...n
\; \; \; \; \; \; \;\; \; \; \; \ 
\textbf{ (2) } 
$$...(the proof goes on)

I'm ok with the rest of the proof (that I didn't write) but I don't understand this beginning: why can we choose such intervals? Where the compactness of **I** and the continuity of $ \alpha $ are used? Why **(1)** implies **(2)** ?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a path $\alpha: I\to S^1$. Note that you can reformulate the statement as follows: "It is possible to subdivide the interval into pieces $[0,1] = [0,t_1]\cup [t_1,t_2]\cup...\cup[t_{n-1},t_n]$  such that the image $\alpha([t_i,t_{i+1}])$ of any piece is contained in an open ball of radius say $1/4$. " My statement is stronger than the one from the book.

Here is how to prove this. Let $\mathcal U$ be the open cover of $S^1$ consisting of all open balls of radius $1/4$. Set $\mathcal V = \{\gamma^{-1}(U)\,|\, U\in \mathcal U\}$. Note that $\mathcal V$ is an open cover of the interval $I$. The result now follows from the Lebegue-number lemma: [Explanations of Lebesgue number lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/explanations-of-lebesgue-number-lemma). There is a number $1/n >0$ such that each set of diameter at most $1/n$ is contained in a set from the cover $\mathcal V$. The partition $[0,1/n] \cup [1/n,2/n]\cup...$ will do the job. $[t_i,t_{i+1}] \subset \gamma^{-1}(U)$ for some $U \in \mathcal U$, hence $\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}])\subset U$ and $U$ is an open ball of radius $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

It is well-known that any continuous functon from a compact metric space to a metric space is *uniformly continuous*. This implies that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|\alpha (t) - \alpha (t')| < 1$ for all $t, t'\in I$ with $|t - t'| < \delta$. Let $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $1/n \le \delta$. Then $t_i = i/n$ ($i=0,\dots,n$) will do.

**(2)**

We have $|\alpha (t_{i-1}) - (-\alpha (t_{i-1}))| = 2$, thus for $t \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ we get
$$|\alpha (t) - (-\alpha (t_{i-1}))| = |\alpha (t_{i-1}) - (-\alpha (t_{i+1})) + \alpha (t) - \alpha (t_{i-1})| \\ \ge  |\alpha (t_{i-1}) - (-\alpha (t_{i+1}))| - | \alpha (t) - \alpha (t_{i-1})| > 2 -1 = 1 ,$$
hence $\alpha (t) \ne -\alpha (t_{i-1})$.